# El título no se visualiza

Tags: html, css

¿Por qué el título `h2` , que está al final del código HTML, no se visualiza?

```css
/* General */
body{
  background-color: #000000;
}

/* ------- */

/* 1.0 - Menu de navegación */

#menu{
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  top:0;
  position: fixed;
}

#menu li{
  float: left;
  min-width: calc(100%/5); /* Cantidad de li */
}
#menu li:first-child a{
  background-color:gray;
}
#menu li a{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
#menu li a:hover{
  background-color:gray;
}
/* ------------------------- */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Astro cosmos</title>
  <link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
<body>
   <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="home.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="maths.html">Matemáticas</a></li>
    <li><a href="physics.html">Física</a></li>
    <li><a href="computacion.html">Computación</a></li>
    <li><a href="others.html">Otros</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <h2 style="color:white;">Holaa</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se ve el título ya que cuando posicionas un elemento con `position: fixed`, este se sale del workflow de la página y, por lo tanto, todo lo que esté en esa posición estará por debajo de dicho elemento (por supuesto, con excepciones).

Una solución es establecer una posición al `body` (`position: relative`) y añadirle la propiedad `top` para posicionarlo a una distancia más abajo de lo que es el menú. En este caso he usado la altura del menú como referencia y he establecido que el `body` esté posicionado con un espacio superior (que no es lo mismo que margen superior) de 50px.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
/* General */
body{
  background-color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

/* ------- */

/* 1.0 - Menu de navegación */

#menu{
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  top:0;
  position: fixed;
}

#menu li{
  float: left;
  min-width: calc(100%/5); /* Cantidad de li */
}
#menu li:first-child a{
  background-color:gray;
}
#menu li a{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
#menu li a:hover{
  background-color:gray;
}
/* ------------------------- */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Astro cosmos</title>
  <link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
<body>
   <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="home.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="maths.html">Matemáticas</a></li>
    <li><a href="physics.html">Física</a></li>
    <li><a href="computacion.html">Computación</a></li>
    <li><a href="others.html">Otros</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <h2 style="color:white;">Holaa</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>La respuesta esta en un comentario.....</strike>

No ves el elemento `<h2>` porque esta detrás del menu, ya que el menú tiene `position: fixed`.

Con un simple `margin-top` verás el elemento.

```css
/* General */
body{
  background-color: #000000;
}

/* ------- */

/* 1.0 - Menu de navegación */

#menu{
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  top:0;
  position: fixed;
}

#menu li{
  float: left;
  min-width: calc(100%/5); /* Cantidad de li */
}
#menu li:first-child a{
  background-color:gray;
}
#menu li a{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
#menu li a:hover{
  background-color:gray;
}
/* ------------------------- */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Astro cosmos</title>
  <link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
<body>
   <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="home.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="maths.html">Matemáticas</a></li>
    <li><a href="physics.html">Física</a></li>
    <li><a href="computacion.html">Computación</a></li>
    <li><a href="others.html">Otros</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <h2 style="color:white; margin-top: 100px;">Holaa</h2> <!-- margin-top ! -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me podrias explicar la solucion

Comment: @EduardoSebastian - Respuesta editada

Comment: Porque position fixed afecta al h2?

Comment: y como sabes que deben ser 100px de margin top ?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian - Bueno es que tienes solo el h2...si tendrías más elementos te afectaria también... te recomiendo que leas [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position) y los 100px... era solo un ejemplo

Comment: Esque ir cambiendole a todos el margin top?!! no hay otra manera?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian - Si claro.... si ves la otra respuesta (sin explicaciones) verás que ha puesta en el body un padding... o lo pones al contenedor (general) que necesitas darle el padding... y listo

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* General */
body{
  background-color: #000000;
  padding-top: 50px; //<------------ esta propiedad
}

/* ------- */

/* 1.0 - Menu de navegación */

#menu{
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  top:0;
  position: fixed;
}

#menu li{
  float: left;
  min-width: calc(100%/5); /* Cantidad de li */
}
#menu li:first-child a{
  background-color:gray;
}
#menu li a{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
#menu li a:hover{
  background-color:gray;
}
/* ------------------------- */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Astro cosmos</title>
  <link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
<body>
   <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="home.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="maths.html">Matemáticas</a></li>
    <li><a href="physics.html">Física</a></li>
    <li><a href="computacion.html">Computación</a></li>
    <li><a href="others.html">Otros</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <h2 style="color:white;">Holaa</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Esta la propiedad que agregamos en los estilos (`padding-top)` afecta a toda la pagina, pero como el menú tiene la propiedad `position: fixed;` se sale de la maquetación y es como si no ocupara tamaño en la pagina

Comment: Como lo has hecho?

Comment: solo ponle en los estilos css a la etiqueta body la propiedad padding-top: 50px; los 50px es lo que mide aproximadamente el menu fixed